# Как узнать путь к проекту в Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, файлы

Пишу программу которая копирует файлы в разные папки. Папка, из которой я копирую файлы должна создаться и лежать в папке проекта (скрин). Мне нужно создать в рабочей директории проекта эту папку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]]

Comment: скрин совершенно "несмотрибельный"

Comment: Проблема то в чем?

Comment: попробуйте его увеличить и все там будит "Смотрибельное"....проблема в том что я незнаю как создать папку проекта в самом проекте.....Т.е. мне нужно что бы я мог просто скопировать проект вместе с exe-ником и не париться что на диске C например у меня создается папка для файлов которые нужно копировать....эту папку нужно создать например в нужно создать в папке проекта.....

Comment: Не, что-то не то. На клиентской машине не будет разворачиваться весь проект, а только исполнимые файлы (ну и возможно вспомогательные), но уж никак не исходники. Какая ваша _реальная_ задача?

Comment: @Ildarik07 внесите обновление в тело вопроса вместо написания комментариев.

Comment: да мне не нужно что бы разворачивался проект! Блин вы меня не понимаете  смотрите..... есть метод который создает папку на диске С... Мне же нужно что бы приложение созавала не на диске с а в самом проекте т.е. папке которую я скопирую на конечную машину

Comment: Тогда уже, наверное не в проекте, а в папке с приложением?

Comment: да наверно в папке приложения....

Comment: как можно этот путь указать?

Comment: Application.ExecutablePath?

Comment: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location ?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы наверняка узнать путь к каталогу исполняемого файла (а я подозреваю что именно *это* вы и пытаетесь узнать), воспользуйтесь `System.Reflection`.
Следует получить у экземпляра класса [Assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=vs.110).aspx) значение свойства [Location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.assembly.location(v=vs.110).aspx). Это будет выглядеть так:

```
var location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
//Для выделения пути к каталогу, воспользуйтесь `System.IO.Path`:
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(location);
```

Соответственно, если путь к вашему файлу выглядит так: `C:\ScriptInWork\MySuperApp.exe`, то в результате выполнения вышеприведенного кода, в переменной `path` вы получите `C:\ScriptInWork`

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, оставить более информативный ответ?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, конечно. Доберусь до компьютера, обязательно расширением и дополню

Answer (score 0):

Папка которая отобразится в проекте, все равно будет физически размещена на диске, где лежит ваш проект. Не создаются только папки решения. Поэтому создайте папку в директории где лежит ваш проект и в "Обозревателе решений" щелкните тумблер "Показывать все файлы".  И вы уведите вашу папку.

Comment: Вообщем мне нужно в конечно итоге получить: скопировать проект на диск c и внутри папок проекта создалась папка.....

Comment: Проект или приложение?

Comment: Напишите куда конкретно, я выложу вам код

Comment: C:\ScriptInWork    например так

Comment: public void DirCreate()
        {
            // Путь к диску где будит создан каталог,где хранятся файлы
            Puth = @"C:\WebMonFiles";
             
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Puth);
            if (!directoryInfo.Exists)
            {
                directoryInfo.Create();
            }
        }
вот что есть сейчас